# How to display MySQL data using tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and trying to make an invoice application using this library. The app will read an Excel file using the Browse button and then save the Excel data into MySQL database which is working fine. However, when I press the Report button, it's not displaying the record on new window and getting halt all the time. Even a new window won't open, it should display the record on the current window. Here is my code:

```
# Import the required Libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import mysql.connector
import xlrd

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called folder_path
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

def show_new_window():
    print("Show new window called")
    # Create the new window
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(app)
    new_window.title("Report")

    # Create a label in the new window
    label = tk.Label(new_window, text="Delivery Report")
    label.pack()

    # Connect to the database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                                password='',
                                host='localhost',
                                database='magnetico')

    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT id_user, Vendor, KM FROM perorder")
    # Get the results
    result = mycursor.fetchall()

    # Close the cursor and connection
    mycursor.close()
    conn.close()

    # Create a button for each row in the result
    for row in result:
        button = tk.Button(new_window, text=str(row))
        button.pack()

# Set the geometry of tkinter frame
app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("900x800")

folder_path = tk.StringVar()

# Add a heading
heading = tk.Label(app, text="Click the Button to browse the Files", font=("Helvetica", 16))
heading.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

lbl1 = tk.Label(app, textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

# Center the button
button2 = tk.Button(app, text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

button = tk.Button(app, text="Report", command=show_new_window)
button.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

# Set the row and column weights
app.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
app.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
app.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

app.mainloop()

# Connect to the database
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                               password='',
                               host='localhost',
                               database='magnetico')

# Open the workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook("mpo1.xls")

# Get the sheet you want
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Order Details")

# Iterate through the rows of the sheet
for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
    # Get the values in the row
    row = sheet.row_values(row_idx)
    # Insert the row into the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO perorder (mp_task_nr, batch_id, dropoff_sequence, id_user_payout_type, task_status, city, fleet, id_user, Name, Vendor, order_date, UID, KM, total_amount, Remarks) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", row)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Node that code beyond `mainloop()` will not be executed until the root window is closed.

Comment: `show_new_window()` works fine for me.  Is there any error when you execute the function?

Comment: There's no error but when I press the Report button it stick on press state and nothing displaying.